# Failed trying to update, using PDO, POO, SINGLETON and MVC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, singleton

Where is the error of the structure in this code, because I have seen that in other code it works well?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setNombre() on
>   bool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\brightside\controlador\usuario.controller.php:95 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\brightside\index.php(15):
>   usuarioController->actualizar() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\brightside\controlador\usuario.controller.php on line
>   95

controller/user.controller.php:

```php
public function actualizar() {
    $id = $_GET["idu"]??"";

    if (!empty($id)):
        $usin = Usuario::getUsuarioById($_GET["idu"]);
        if (isset($_GET["nom"])):
            $usin->setNombre($_GET["nom"]);
            $usin->setUsuario($_GET["usu"]);
            $usin->setEmail($_GET["ema"]);
            $usin->setPassword($_GET["pass"]);

            $usin->actualizar();
            $this->index();
        else:
            $nombre = $usin->getNombre();
            $usuario = $usin->getUsuario();
            $email = $usin->getEmail();
            $password = $usin->getPassword();
            require_once "vista/actualizar.usuario.php";
        endif;
        else:
        echo "mal";
    endif;
}
```

model/user.php:

```php
public function actualizar() {
    $db = Database::getInstancia();
    $db->query("UPDATE usuario SET nombre=:nom, usuario=:usu, email=:ema, password=:pass WHERE usuario=:usu;",
        [
        ":nom"=>$this->nombre,
        ":usu"=>$this->usuario,
        ":ema"=>$this->email,
        ":pass"=>$this->password
        ]);
}
```

Comment: `$usin` is a boolean while you're using it as an object. Check what you get back from `Usuario::getUsuarioById($_GET["idu"]);` instead of assuming it returns what you want.

Comment: `$usin` is false, so it failed to find that user. Double-check the value of `$_GET["idu"]` and make sure that user ID exists.

Comment: **Warning:** You seem to be storing the passwords in clear text. Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: I would also recommend that you use POST instead of GET when you send data to the back end for updates etc. POST is for sending data. GET is for getting data.

Comment: Ideally you should check if `$usin` is a object with `is_object()` or a faster method `(object)$usin === $usin` after you use `Usuario::getUsuarioById(..)`  And return `NULL` in the `Usuario::getUsuarioById(..)` when no record(s) where found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I would expect that `is_object()` is faster than first casting the result as an object and then do a strict type comparison. (I don't have any proof though)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson In general PHP is faster in type casting than in calling functions, but it all depends on the use case. In this scenario I doubt it would make much difference and the function call is more readable.

Comment: for `is_int($value)` or `(int)$value === $value` for example there is a difference @MagnusEriksson for objects the size of the object might also matter which is faster also PHP engine seams to matter.. the object cast in PHP 5.6.29 was faster then calling `is_object()` and in PHP 7 `is_object()` was the faster method.